# How to pre-allocate a structure vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures, pre-allocation

In matlab, the function struct allow to pre-allocate a structure like this

```
S = struct(field1,{},field2,{},...,fieldN,{})
```

But I need S to be a vector of structures of let's say a length of 100, and I don't know how to do that. I want to do this so that later I can assign

```
S(60).field1=1234;
```

Without making S to change size as a consequence of the assignment.

Comment: Assign the last element first, possibly with temporary variables, then the entire vector is constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the size of S trough the size of the values you assign to each field during the creation of the structure. In this case the following line would do the trick

```
S = struct(field1,cell(1,100),field2,cell(1,100),...,fieldN,cell(1,100));
```

As pointed out by Cris Luengo in the comments, you can also use a scalar for all but one field. Therefore, the following line would have the exact same result

```
S = struct(field1,cell(1,100),field2,[],...,fieldN,[]);
```

Comment: Note that you can use a scalar for all but one field, and get the same result.

Comment: @CrisLuengo good point, I've added it to the answer. Thanks.